# sentence structure of past-future pattern

Tags: tenses, syntactic-analysis, backshifting

How can I make a sentence , in which I am talking about past with the reference of future?
I mean,what is the sentence structure of past-future sentence.
 for **example**. *

> I reached at London two week ago,i was full of fear at that time,i was
>   just thinking about,what will happen tomorrow?

*
 some how the above sentence is wrong please correct it,and please guide me how to correctly make these pattern sentences

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine (in that regard) if you are talking about "tomorrow" relative to the time of speaking. To fix other issues:

> I reached London two weeks ago. I was full of fear at the time, just thinking about what will happen tomorrow.

(Or perhaps you meant "just" as in "I was thinking only of what will happen tomorrow").

There's no problem mixing the past "I was full of fear" with the future "what will happen tomorrow" if that's what you mean.

You can also use the *am/is/are going to* form of the future tense:

> I reached London two weeks ago. I was full of fear at the time, just thinking about what is going to happen tomorrow.

I however you meant a time future to then, but past to now, (you arrived 14 days ago and you were thinking about what was going to happen 13 days ago) there are two forms you can use.

The first uses *would* much as the future tense uses *will*:

> I reached London two weeks ago. I was full of fear at the time, just thinking about what would happen the following day.

The second uses *was/were going to* much as the future uses *am/are/is going to*:

> I reached London two weeks ago. I was full of fear at the time, just thinking about what was going to happen the following day.